# Playwright: unable to login via API setting cookie (able to do it with Cypress)

Tags: api, cookies, automation, cypress, playwright

I'm trying to implemented login via API following [Playwright's guidelines](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth) but somehow nothing seems to be working.
As a comparison I've built the same in Cypress and it works out of the box:

**Context:**

- Playwright Version: 1.30
- Operating System: Mac
- Node.js version: v16.19.0
- Browser: Chromium

I am unable to make a simple API login that works perfectly using Cypress instead. Let me share the 2 code snippets for comparison:

Simple test case:

1. API request to the login end-point - Auth token is retrieved
2. set the auth token as a cookie
3. navigate to a page that is accessible only if authenticated

**Code Snippet**

Cypress (working fine)

```js
const body = {
  username: 'username...',
  password: 'password',
  rememberMe: true,
};

describe('Login via API to management console', () => {
  it('Login via API to management console', () => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: loginEndPoint,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body,
    }).then((response) => {
      cy.setCookie('Authorization', `Token ${response.body.data.token}`);
    });

    cy.visit(`/management`);
  });
});
```

Playwright (not working)

```js
test('Login via API', async ({ browser }) => {
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  const loginResponse = await context.request.post(`https://${process.env.MANAGEMENT_URL}/web/api/v2.1/users/login`, {
    data: {
      username: process.env.MANAGEMENT_USER,
      password: process.env.MANAGEMENT_PASSWORD,
      rememberMe: true,
    }
  });

  const {
    data: { token },
  } = await loginResponse.body().then((b) => {
    return JSON.parse(b.toString());
  });

  expect(token).toMatch(/^[a-z0-9]{80}$/)

  await context.addCookies([{ name: 'Authorization', value: `Token ${token}`, path: '/', domain: `https://${process.env.MANAGEMENT_URL}` }]);

  await page.goto(`https://${process.env.MANAGEMENT_URL}/management/`);

  await expect(page).toHaveURL(/management/);
});
```

**Describe the bug**

Both scripts are successful at retrieving the authentication token but somehow either I'm doing something wrong with setting the cookie in Playwright or there is an issue. I'd assume the 2 scripts should be comparable.
Furthermore: I've tried to execute login via UI using global-setup, saving the storage-state, loading it before running the test and it fails also in this case... so there is something that is not setting properly the state in this case or the cookie in the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why the cookie approach wasn’t working, perhaps the `https://` part should be removed from the domain?

That being said, in Playwright you shouldn’t even need to do that especially within a single test, looking at [the Playwright docs on signing in via the API](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#sign-in-via-api-request) and [related page about the `request` context](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext) particularly under cookie management. The associated request and browser contexts share cookies, so once you complete the login request, the browser should already have the cookie state too and be logged in, so you should be able to just remove getting the token and adding the cookie. Or you can login with the API in the global setup even, as that doc showed. Just make sure in that case to save the storage state, and specify the same file in your config.

I see you tried the global setup approach (through the UI, but you can use the API since you have it), not sure what happened there. I would say to ensure that you specified the storageState in the config; I would be curious how you loaded it as mentioned, and if you’re still having problems maybe share the code you’re using for that piece?

Hope that helps or we can troubleshoot further!